# The problem of changing values in implement inheritance using Object.create

Tags: javascript

As we all know, we can use `let obj1 = Object.create(obj)` to make the prototype of obj1 point to obj. But the problem I found was, why is the change between the two not two-way? As the code shows.

```
var obj = { val: 1 };
var obj1 = Object.create(obj);

obj.val = 2;
console.log(obj.val);  // 2
console.log(obj1.val);  // 2

obj1.val = 3;
console.log(obj.val);  // 2
console.log(obj1.val);  // 3
```

Why do I change the attribute value of obj and obj1 will change. But I change the attribute value of obj1, but it will not change to obj?

Why is there such a difference? I can't understand. Do you know? Could you tell me the reason? Thanks!

Comment: You are "shadowing" the parent object's `val` property when you create a property on the child object with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to access a property on an object, javascript first checks that objects own properties. If it finds it, great, it resolves to that value. If it doesn't, it walks the prototype chain to the parent and checks there. It continues walking up the prototype chain until it either finds it, or reaches the end of the chain, in which case the value is undefined.

So when you access `obj1.val`, it first checks obj1.val. In your first case, it fails to find it so it checks obj.val and returns the 2 it finds there. In your second case, it finds it as an own property of 3 and does not check obj.val.

When instead you access `obj.val`, it checks obj.val. In both cases, it finds it, and it's equal to 2. Even if it failed to find an own property, it still wouldn't check obj1, since obj1 is not in its prototype chain. It would just check the root `Object.prototype` (which is where the base properties of objects like `.toString` are defined).

Answer (score 0):

This simple example shows a differnt way to create a prototype with exactly the same results. This shows how the inheritance chain works and the result of "shadowing".

```js
const GrandChild = {};
const Child = {};
const Parent = {};
const GrandParent = {
  name: "grandparent"
};

GrandChild.__proto__ = Child;
Child.__proto__ = Parent;
Parent.__proto__ = GrandParent;
GrandChild.__proto__ = Child;

console.log(GrandChild.name, Child.name, Parent.name, GrandParent.name);

Child.name = "Child";

console.log(GrandChild.name, Child.name, Parent.name, GrandParent.name);
```